# Trigger animation by delay or if scroll

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am using nextJS with framer-motion.

I would like to display a part of my website (i.e. the header menu) if at least one condition below is met  :

1. the user is on the website since more than 5s (~delay the animation by 5s)
2. the part the user sees is not the very top of the page ( e.g. he scrolled, or refreshed the page not at the top)

Currently, I could implement condition 1. using delay.
I heard about useViewportScroll but not sure how to integrate it in my current configuration

```
  <motion.div initial={{ opacity: 0 }} animate={{ opacity: 1 }} transition={{   delay: 5, duration : 2  }} className=" ">
```

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sandbox that I believe does what you're looking for. It uses `setTimeout` to initially delay the animation by 5 seconds. If the user scrolls before 5 seconds, `useViewportScroll` will show the header.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-proskuriakova-u4hfeu?file=/src/App.js)